# Why di I get ERROR: "missing COLUMNS keyword" during INSERT INTO table statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, xmltype

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTable
( 
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    DOC XMLTYPE,

    CONSTRAINT ID_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

My `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO XMLTable (ID, DOC) 
VALUES (1, '<record><name>John</name><marks>5</marks></record>');
```

Error:

> INSERT INTO XMLTable (ID, DOC)
>   VALUES (1, 'John5')
>   Error at Command Line : 22 Column : 25
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing COLUMNS keyword
>   02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

I use an Oracle database.

Comment: ```XMLTABLE``` is a reserved word in Oracle's SQL.
See here: [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm)

Try replacing the name of the table, possibly conveying meaning as to what it's meant to contain.

Comment: This works for me, thank you very much.